# Sort diagrams alphabetically in Doxygen using doxyfile configuration

Tags: doxygen

I'll draft my question as per the suggestion provided by StackOverflow

**1. Problem summary**
While generating documentation using doxygen (Environment Ubuntu 20.04), I can observe the sequence diagrams (as a subpage) are not listed in numerical order (i.e. improperly sorted).

***Image:***

[image: Sequences generated from plantUML]

**2. What I've tried**
In the doxyfile that I use, I set YES to the flags listed below.

```
SORT_BRIEF_DOCS
SORT_BY_SCOPE_NAME
SORT_GROUP_NAMES
SORT_MEMBERS_CTORS_1ST
SORT_MEMBER_DOCS
```

Now, you might wonder why I did that. Since I am new to generating documentation with doxygen, and the flag name "SORT" caught my attention, I tried to set these flags to YES. However, the end result was not what I expected. It is evident that I am doing something that is incorrect, and it would be great if someone could point me towards the proper direction.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using (`doxygen -v`). What is the extension of the "sequence diagrams" how do you include them on a subpage in other words please provide a small example showing the problem.

Comment: Version is 1.8.17. I have a tool that generates the dox file. Maybe something requires to be fixed in that side. Thanks for the hint